# Изменение радиобаттон'ов окна C#

Tags: c#

День добрый, господа. Как нибудь возможно программно обратиться к данному окну и поменять текущий радио баттон на нужный мне ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно, как и большинство настроек ОС windows это хранится в реестре, поэтому самый простой вариант сделать -- это а) отследить какие ключи меняются (при помощи программ контроля реестра) б) в своём коде на c# манипулировать нужными ключами реестра (не забывая о правах доступа)

Comment: Можно пример подобной программы ?

Comment: Их много. Ну вот RegMon https://www.ixbt.com/soft/regmon.shtml

Comment: Нашел тему где и был ответ..все равно спасибо, пригодится :)
[ссылка](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/be24d4ef-1104-40f2-bde4-5aab9d4d8447/104810791084107710851077108510801103?forum=windows7ru)

Comment: Оформите ответом. По ссылке может протухнуть - у майкрософта постоянно ссылки протухают.

Answer (score 0):

Источник — Майкрософт

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects]
"VisualFXSetting"=dword:00000002
```

Все ниже в этой ветке — это все настройки по одно значение dword:00000000 отключено dword:00000001 включено

Примерная реализация

```
RegistryKey linkT = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\VisualEffects", true);
if (linkT != null)
{

    linkT.SetValue("VisualFXSetting", 2, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    linkT.Close();
}
linkT.Close();
```